# asp.net core controller action route uses encoded slash to determine route (IIS only)

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, kestrel

I have an asp.net core 2.2 mvc action method and `GET` it from the client JavaScript code :

```
[Route("/search/{searchterm}")]
public IActionResult Search(string searchterm)
{
    // code
}
```

Now, when I navigate to search with the searchstring `abc/def`
the uri in the browser is `/search/abc%2Fdef`  because the / gets encoded

I get a `404` though, because the routing attribute decoded the slash and the says `/search/abc/def` does not match my route.
What I want is to treat the `%2F` as a normal piece of content so the searchstring is `abc/def` inside of my action method.

Funny(?) thing is, this does not happen on my local machine where I run from VS2017 (which runs Kestrel I guess) but only on the test server where it runs on IIS.

Is this an IIS thing? or maybe the loadbalancer is doing something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use an asterisk to indicate that `searchterm` can contain slashes. This is called a [catch-all parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#route-template-reference), and looks like this:

```cs
[Route("/search/{**searchterm}")]
public IActionResult Search(string searchterm)
{
    // code
}
```

From the documentation:

> You can use an asterisk (`*`) or double asterisk (`**`) as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI. These are called a catch-all parameters. For example, `blog/{**slug}` matches any URI that starts with `/blog` and has any value following it, which is assigned to the slug route value. Catch-all parameters can also match the empty string.
>
> The catch-all parameter escapes the appropriate characters when the route is used to generate a URL, including path separator (/) characters. For example, the route `foo/{*path}` with route values `{ path = "my/path" }` generates `foo/my%2Fpath`. Note the escaped forward slash. To round-trip path separator characters, use the `**` route parameter prefix. The route `foo/{**path}` with `{ path = "my/path" }` generates `foo/my/path`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Any idea on why there is different behaviour on IIS vs local development server?

Comment: @Métoule Is there a way to do the equivalent of this? [Route("/search/{**searchterm}/{**additionalSearch}")]

Comment: @BradenBrown it's not possible to have two `catch-all` parameters, because there's no way to know where one stops and the other starts (e.g. `/search/one/two/three/four`). You can use query parameters instead (e.g. `/search?searchterm=one/two/three&additionalSearch=four`).

Comment: @Métoule That's what I was thinking. That's true, for some reason I didn't think about using query params... Thanks! +1